# Haskell percentage of char in a string

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a program that receives a STRING and returns the percentage of 'C' and 'A' in it. However it is going to me wrong, this is my code:

```
function' :: [Char] -> Double
function' xs = 100* ( fromIntegral final0 )
                    where final0 = length $ filter (\x-> x == 'C'|| x == 'G') xs
```

if I run: function '$ replicate 20' C ', return me 2000.0 and should give me 1.0

Answer (score 2):

### Some errors in the question

You said

> 'C' and 'A'

While your code says

> \x-> x == 'C'|| x == 'G'

### What you're doing

You're measuring the number of `C`s and `G`s, and `*100`, and return the result.

### How to solve

do not `*100`, do `/ length xs`.

### Solution

```
function' xs = fromIntegral final0 / fromIntegral final1
                where final0 = length $ filter (\x-> x == 'C'|| x == 'G') xs
                      final1 = length xs
```